# Automatically generate SSIS package from BIML script

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis, ssis-2008, biml

Once you have finished your BIML script (using BIDS SQL Server 2008) to create the SSIS package you simply right click the BIML file and click Generate SSIS packages.

How do i generate the SSIS packges via code e.g. C# or SQL? I can imagine some kinda of shell script to the BimlEngine.dll e.g. BimlEngine.dll -"myFileServer\myBimlScript", "generate SSIS packages"

I have found this c# code project 
https://github.com/jgsato/BimlGen

and in particular this file 
https://github.com/jgsato/BimlGen/blob/master/BimlGenerator.cs

i'm just not sure how to use it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: pls let me know why do you need to generate SSIS package from BIML script

Comment: I have never come across /heard about a situvation like this..so please let mek now the context

Comment: @user1254579: I know for me, I'd want to do it to hook into build automation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you linked is a mechanism for generating Biml, xml, based on SMO.

Your intention is to reproduce the right click/generate SSIS package, thus converting the Biml XML into a DTSX's XML. To do this, you'll need to look at how [BidsHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) does it. In the class [BimlExpandPlugin](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SSIS/Biml/BimlExpandPlugin.cs), you'll find version specific calls to the `BidsHelper.CompileBiml`

```
ValidationReporter validationReporter = BidsHelper.CompileBiml(
    typeof(AstNode).Assembly, 
    "Varigence.Hadron.BidsHelperPhaseWorkflows.xml", 
    "Compile", bimlScriptPaths, 
    new List<string>(), 
    tempTargetDirectory, 
    projectDirectory, 
    SqlServerVersion.SqlServer2008, 
    SsisVersion.Ssis2012, 
    SsasVersion.Ssas2008, 
    DeployPackagesPlugin.IsLegacyDeploymentMode(project) ? 
        SsisDeploymentModel.Package : 
        SsisDeploymentModel.Project);
```

Something to note is that the folks at Varigence provide the functionality that exists for BidsHelper as a subset of what their product, [Mist](http://varigence.com/Products/Mist/Capabilities), is capable of. One of those things is skipping the XML mashing and just use native .NET objects to create and describe SSIS objects. If you want to work with the .NET objects, then you'll need to buy a license.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work. I tried it, but as you can see in the below SO thread, it didn't work.

[Expand BIML files programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760907/expand-biml-files-programmatically)