# schedule BIML generation of scripts?

Tags: ssis, scheduling, sql-server-2017, biml, ssis-2017

I have some BIML scripts that (working together)

1. check a folder for cvs files
2. create packages to import those files

This works like a charm, however, wehenever a file is added (or removed) to that folder, I need to regenerate the packages by running the BIML scripts.

Can this be automated? So othat the biml script is run, the packages are created and the packages are then executed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760907/expand-biml-files-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amira mentions, you need a licensed installation of the BimlStudio product.

The command you are looking for is bimlc

BimlC references

- [Building using the Command Line](https://docs.varigence.com/BimlFlex/build-solution/command-line-build)
- [Biml Compiler (bimlc.exe) options](https://docs.varigence.com/BimlStudio/miscellaneous/biml-compiler-command-line-options)

I thought we had a chapter on CI/CD in [The Biml Book](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484231340) but I'm not seeing it at the moment. Bimlc is mentioned in the SSAS chapter but I thought there was more info on it.

Comment: I am leaving BIML Studio for now. Scripts that work in my VS do not work in BIML Studio. I need to do some more studying, find out how in earth this tool works :| For now I will instruct my colleagues to generate and deploy the packages manually whenever a new file is placed in that folder. Getting quite frustrated :|

Comment: Reach out to support @ Varigence if BimlStudio is not behaving well. For a paid product, that's part of the benefit. Only thing that comes to mind that can be different is whether you specify a script is live vs reference. Worst case, I can spare 15/30 minutes if you want to screenshare what's happening. 7 hour time zone difference between us

Answer (score 1):

By automating the right click/generate SSIS package you mean the conversion Biml XML into a DTSX's XML.

[BidsHelper](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/) helps you achieve that using [BimlExpandPlugin](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11352635/) class

In the class `BimlExpandPlugin`, you'll find version specific calls to the [BidsHelper.CompileBiml](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11352635/)

```
ValidationReporter validationReporter = BidsHelper.CompileBiml(typeof(AstNode).Assembly, "Varigence.Hadron.BidsHelperPhaseWorkflows.xml", "Compile", bimlScriptPaths, new List < string > (), tempTargetDirectory, projectDirectory, SqlServerVersion.SqlServer2008, ssisVersion, SsasVersion.Ssas2008);

ValidationReporter validationReporter = BidsHelper.CompileBiml(typeof(AstNode).Assembly, "Varigence.Hadron.BidsHelperPhaseWorkflows.xml", "Compile", bimlScriptPaths, new List < string > (), tempTargetDirectory, projectDirectory, SqlServerVersion.SqlServer2005, SsisVersion.Ssis2005, SsasVersion.Ssas2005);
```

[Varigence](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress) offers that functionality existing for BidsHelper with their product [Varigence Mist (now called BimlStudio)](https://docs.varigence.com/bimlstudio/release-notes/mist-4.0).

Note :

The BIDS Helper add-on for Microsoft SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) and the Varigence Mist (now called BimlStudio) integrated development environment; both tools translate Biml metadata into SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) and SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) assets for the Microsoft SQL Server platform. However, emitters can be created to compile Biml for any desired BI platform.

Comment: BidsHelper is deprecated. The IP in both BidsHelper and BimlExpress is intended to _only_ be used for interactive build sessions. To get automated builds, you need to purchase a license for BimlStudio.