# Automatically create column in destination table based on source column in SSIS or in SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis

I have requirement to create automatically columns in sql server table using ssis or sql.(you can suggest)

Scenario is like this,

In ODBC Source table I have 10 columns.
Using SSIS transformations I am importing 10 columns data into my destination SQL server table.

On second day I have 12 columns in source.....(Here is the problem)
Now I need 12 columns in destination also and number of columns always increment everyday.

How can I handle this using any tool or code ....Please suggest.

Thanks in advance  ...

Comment: and on the third day you have 13 columns? SSIS doesn't play well with this situation. It needs consistent metadata. (i.e. column count and data types). Can you explain the nature of this data? Is there an upper limit to the number of columns that will dynamically appear?

Comment: No there is no limit ....because its source...but it not more than 10 columns everyday.

Comment: You can suggest other tool also or any other method

Comment: SSIS is definitely unsuitable for this. If you are comfortable with C#, write a  C# console app. This kind of 'add a column to a table every table' seems like a bad design. You should normally be adding a row not a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create BIML and do automation using C# to generate ssis package.

More details are available at below link

[Automatically generate SSIS package from BIML script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455000/automatically-generate-ssis-package-from-biml-script)

Answer (score 0):

@Nick.McDermaid already said it, but adding columns dynamically to a table is a really *bad* design decision.  For one thing, it'll cause no end of problems when you try to work with the data in the table.  How will you know when a blank column means "unknown", means "no data in this load", or "this column didn't exist in the load"?

Comment: there is no issue with design, the requirement is like this, for the same i am looking for dynamic column create solution ..and the the table is staging table